# Getting logged-in user details in post_user_login event in PyroCMS

Tags: events, authentication, pyrocms

How to get the details of the just logged-in user in the `post_user_login` [event](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/developers/tools/events) in [PyroCMS](https://www.pyrocms.com/)?

What I have tried:

1. [`$this->current_user`](https://www.pyrocms.com/documentation/2.0/developers/developer-tools/constants-globals) does not work, unless page is refreshed, even though the controllers are inheriting `Public_Controller` or `Admin_Controller`, thus implying availability of `$this->current_user` ([documentation](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/developers/basics/base-controllers#my_controller)).

Why do I need this:

1. To get (at least) user id or profile id, so that I can fetch more details and take action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = $this->ci->current_user ? $this->ci->current_user : $this->ci->ion_auth->get_user();
```

Source: https://forum.pyrocms.com/discussion/25095/get-logged-in-user-in-post_user_login-event
Author: [andym](https://forum.pyrocms.com/profile/3302/andym)